# How to stop fetching duplicate data from a web service

Tags: android, android-listview, android-contentprovider

I have an Android project that requires updating listview with data obtained from a Web Service, this data will however first be persisted to a local database and then served from the local database to the listview using a content provider. I implemented this requirement successfully except that the listview is showing multiples sets of the same data. That is if you run the app 5 times, there will be five sets of the same data shown in the listview.

My question is where and how can I implement some sort of counter or loop that ensures that only one set of the data is shown.

Here is my implementation steps

1. The Fragment uses the Loader API to load data from the Content
   Provider, here is the onCreateLoader()

   ```
   public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loaderId, Bundle arg) {
   return (new CursorLoader(getActivity(), Provider.Programs.CONTENT_URI,
           PROJECTION, null, null, null));
   ```

   }
2. After the onCreateLoader, the adapter is refreshed like so

   ```
   public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
   mAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
   ```

   }
3. In the Content Provider class, I initialize the local database and
   call an AsyncTask that performs the web service call

   ```
   public boolean onCreate() {

   dbhelper = new LocalDatabase(getContext());
   startWebService();
   return((dbhelper == null) ? false : true);
   ```

   }

   ```
   private void startWebService(){
   HttpAsyncTask asyncTask = new HttpAsyncTask();
   asyncTask.execute();
   ```

   }

Then within the AsyncTask is where I fetch the data from the REST endpoint, parse it and then call the Insert method of the Content Provider class to add the data to the Database and notify the Provider that data has changed

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
            int lenght = jsonArray.length();

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
              JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
              String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
              values.put(Programs.NAME, name);
              insert(Programs.CONTENT_URI, values);

            }               
            Log.i("Data Changed", "Data changed " + lenght);
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(Programs.CONTENT_URI, null);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And here is how I get the data from the database

```
@Override
    public Cursor query(Uri url, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
            String sort) {
            SQLiteQueryBuilder qb=new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
            qb.setTables(TABLE);
            String orderBy;

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(sort)) {
              orderBy=Programs.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER;
            }
            else {
              orderBy=sort;
            }

            Cursor c=
                qb.query(dbhelper.getReadableDatabase(), new String[]{"_id", "name"}, selection,
                         selectionArgs, null, null, orderBy);
            c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), url);
            return(c);  
    }
```

This works if you run the app once, but if you run it multiple time, it will keep fetching and duplicating the data until you stop. Where and how can I implement a counter that tells it not to fetch or save or display the sames sets of data.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using API for getting data from database?

Comment: Or are you using SQLite database? Default database in phone?

Comment: I am using Content Provider API to get the data from the Database

Answer (score 0):

Does the object have an ID ?
Does the object happen to have fields with "modified_date" or "created_date"?

I think the best approach would be to create 2 lists : 1 list contains the objects from the server, and one list contains the objects you have in your local database. Then you just compare the 2 lists, either by ID (which is supposedly unique) and / or by date.

From the 1st list of objects (webservice objects) you remove the ones you already have in the second list, and save only the new ones. Or if you are interested in updating the local ones, then update them.

Comment: The object currently have and ID and Name field, your suggestions makes sense and I will experiment with it

Answer (score 0):

Change your database. Add a new field named **accessed** or something with default value to be **false**.

And when you fetch data from the database immediately update the field to be **true**.

So your new SQL would be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE accessed = 'false'
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by creating a lookup query on the local database that check if an item exist and returns a boolean like so

```
public boolean ProgramExists(String name) {
        db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + PROGRAM_TABLE + " where " + KEY_NAME + "='" + name + "'", null);
           boolean exists = false;
           if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
               exists = (cursor.getCount() > 0);
        }
           cursor.close();
           return exists;
        }
```

Then I modified the onPostExecute method of the AsyncTask to check if the item exists in the database and if yes, to skip and if no to add it like so:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
                int lenght = jsonArray.length();

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                  JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                  String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                  if (!dbhelper.ProgramExists(name)) {
                      values.put(Programs.NAME, name);
                      insert(Programs.CONTENT_URI, values);
                }                 
                }               
                Log.i("Data Changed", "Data changed " + lenght);
                getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(Programs.CONTENT_URI, null);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

That solved the problem and there is no more duplicate entries.

Comment: Seems like a good solution. I would strongly advise you to change your query to bound variables though. The rawquery opens you up to all kinds of nastiness. Especially when communicating over the web